# Bootstrap button loses width on dropdown click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to get the btn-group-justified to work so that the buttons fill the width of a cell.  It works great with single buttons, but not when using a dropdown button.  The button displays fine, but when clicked, the width of the button disappears.

code:

```
  <div class="btn-group-justified">
    <a type="button" class="btn-block btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Right dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 0px" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: try something like button a:hover { required width }

Comment: you still need the `btn-group` class on your `div.btn-group-justified`. Why do you have `min-width` set to 0 on your `ul.dropdown-menu` element?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a simple dropdown element, and add a `right: 0` on your `.dropdown-menu` :

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-justified"> <!-- custom .dropdown-justified class -->
    <a class="btn-block btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.dropdown-justified .dropdown-menu {
    right: 0;
}
```

**[Bootply](http://bootply.com/102006)**